# Override init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) not working like expected - Swift

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm trying to subclass a UITableViewCell in Swift.

I've tried this:

```
class CUISwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var label = UILabel()
    var switchControl = UISwitch()

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Set up UI
    }
}
```

But I get a compiler error when calling `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`:

> Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UITableViewCell'

So what I understand is that I must call `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!)`, but then I will lose all the setups made in Interface Builder. If I not overriding initWithCoder where should I set up my views?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to setup your views, or perform any custom initialisation of your objects that have been archived using interface builder, you can do so by overriding **awakeFromNib**. Every object that has been created using interface builder will get this method called when it is unarchived from Nib. And overriding this method will also keep your interface builder setups intact.